# Cannot Set Property ... of undefined --- bizarre

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm getting a bizarre error in Chrome...  check out the screenshot below.

I define record using object literal syntax.

I try setting the "id" property and get the exception.

I've tried both :

```
record['id'] = 'wtf';
```

and also

```
record.id = 'wtf';
```

I use this type of syntax all over the place in my script.... what could be going on here ?
Is this a bug in Chrome ?

[image]

EDIT :
I've solved the problem for now, but I'm still not sure why this is happening.
I moved the definition of record to occur outside of the if block.  Anyone know what could be occurring ?  I thought all variable declarations were scoped to the function and therefore this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error (on Chrome 7 & Firefox on Mac). From the info here and the screen shot, it looks like there's nothing wrong with your code. What is the value of `record` right before the "erroneous" line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is most likely that `dl` is less than or equal to zero, so the statement that initializes `record` doesn't get executed. From your indentation, it looks like you intended for both statements to be part of the `if` block, but with no braces, the `record['id'] = 'wtf';` statement gets executed no matter what.

By moving the variable initialization outside the if statement, you forced it to happen in any case and moved the assignment inside the if block (which, I'm assuming is what you wanted).

Probably a better way to solve it is adding braces like this:

```
if (dl > 0) {
    var record = {};

    record.id = 'wtf';
}
```

Unless you really do want to initialize `record` in both cases.

You are correct about variable *declarations* being scoped to the function, but the *assignment* doesn't happen until you get to that point in the code. `record` was in scope, but it still had its default value of `undefined` because you hadn't assigned anything to it yet.

Comment: Wow.  Some bugs are self-inflicted. Nice catch !

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, no reason it shouldn't work. Are you sure it's referring to that exact line? what if you `alert(record)` before you set it? Have you tried to debug it yet?

Comment: Actually, I think I've solved the problem just now ... but still I'm not sure why this is happening.   I moved the definition of record outside of the if-block and it seems to work... I'll update the main question.

Comment: @rvandervort: if you do discover the cause, be sure to share the reason!